# Unable to connect my mongodb atlas server

Tags: linux, mongoose, node-modules, mongo-memory-server

I am getting this version error i have tried almost versions of MongoMemoryServerbut getting same error while trying to start my node.js app. is there any solution??

"Could not find any valid Release File, using fallback information
Couldnt parse dist information, please report this to https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server/issues

Unknown/unsupported linux "unknown(undefined)". Falling back to legacy MongoDB build!

Starting the MongoMemoryServer Instance failed, enable debug log for more information. Error:
Error: Status Code is 403 (MongoDB's 404)

This means that the requested version-platform combination doesn't exist
Used Url: "https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-5.0.13.tgz"

Try to use different version 'new MongoMemoryServer({ binary: { version: 'X.Y.Z' } })'

List of available versions can be found here: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community/releases/archive
at ClientRequest. (/home/u971646280/domains/jemishkakadiya.com/public_html/server/node_modules/mongodb-memory-server-core/lib/util/MongoBinaryDownload.js:320:36)

at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)

at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:28)

at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:618:27)

at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)

at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:482:22)

at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:28)

at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)

at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)

at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)"

Answer (score 0):

For whoever stumble on this error again, it mostly as a result of unavailability of the binary release MongoMemoryServer. Visit https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community/releases/archive to get the url for of the binary compactible with your machine setup should be in form of (https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu2204-7.0.3.tgz)

In my own case for example, my os is 23.04 and i had to use 22.04 for it to work as 23.04 isn't available as at the time of writing this.

In your package.json file, paste as below

```json
  "config": {
    "mongodbMemoryServer": {
      "downloadUrl": "https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu2204-7.0.3.tgz"
    }
  }
```

you can also make use of the environment variable as discussed here https://nodkz.github.io/mongodb-memory-server/docs/api/config-options